# What could be causing my GFCI outlet to trip?

Tags: gfci

I have a GFCI outlet in my garage that keeps shutting off. I have unplugged all utilities from it and it still trips off. I replaced it with another GFCI outlet. When I hooked up that new outlet it has a green light on it indicating that it is hooked up but the outlet and the circuit it is on no longer has power. I put the old one back on and it worked for a couple of months then as I added Christmas lights to the circuit it started tripping off again. I again took off all the lights and appliances to it and it still trips off. 
Any suggestions on how to correct this issue?

Answer (score -1):

GFCI outlets break.  They don't last very long.     I recommend replace it with a regular outlet and put a GFCI breaker in the panel.   They are way more user friendly and cheaper.

Comment: A GFCI outlet usually costs $35 - $50 - an GFCI outlet about $13. Not cheaper in my math class - unless you have to replace two outlets for the life of a typical GFCI breaker.  A circuit which was not set up for GFCI may have outlets and fixtures which you will not want on a GFCI circuit - motors etc.